# how to pass numeric array from bash to csh

Tags: arrays, bash, csh

Firstly, in my defense: I'm only using csh because my group has a *lot* of legacy csh. We do scientific programming; a lotta folks apparently learned to use csh back in the SunOS/Solaris days, and didn't give up despite the linux/bash transition, and despite the (IMHO obvious) superiority of the latter. Secondly, apologies if this is a FAQ, but I haven't found an answer via SO or googling generally, and I have devoted some effort to both.

That being said:

I want to drive from bash some legacy csh scripts, as a first step toward [rewriting, removing] the latter. bash->csh works fine for scalar environment variables ('envvars'), in that I can export them from bash and read them from csh as expected.

Not arrays, however ... **until [Chris J. Kiick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20625229/915044) below!** Following example is updated to include Kiick's answer, and the results it produces. Put the following 2 files in the same directory, ...

**array_writer.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
### Test writing an array, passing it to csh, and reading it there.

THIS="$0"
THIS_DIR="$(readlink -f $(dirname ${THIS}))"
THIS_FN="$(basename ${THIS})"
MESSAGE_PREFIX="${THIS_FN}:"
ERROR_PREFIX="${MESSAGE_PREFIX} ERROR:"

PARTNER_FN='array_reader.csh'
PARTNER_DIR="${THIS_DIR}"
PARTNER_FP="${PARTNER_DIR}/${PARTNER_FN}"

export YEAR='2007'
# month-related arrays for ${YEAR}
declare -a BDOM=(0 31 59 90 120 151 181 212 243 273 304 334) # 0-based-Julian of first day of each month
declare -a MDAY=(31 28 31 30 31 30 31 31 30 31 30 31) # days in each month, length=12

echo -e "${MESSAGE_PREFIX} YEAR='${YEAR}':"
# start debugging
# use subshell for IFS
( IFS=',' ; echo -e "\tBDOM=${BDOM[*]}" )
( IFS=',' ; echo -e "\tMDAY=${MDAY[*]}" )
#   end debugging

### Direct export of arrays fails, but this works!
### Note it actually exports a string: see handling in partner
echo -e "${MESSAGE_PREFIX} about to call ${PARTNER_FP}:\n"
# from https://stackoverflow.com/a/20625229/915044
bdom=${BDOM[*]} mday=${MDAY[*]} ${PARTNER_FP}
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]] ; then
  echo -e "\n${ERROR_PREFIX} failed or not found\n"
else
  echo -e "\n${MESSAGE_PREFIX} ${PARTNER_FP} returned successfully"
fi
```

**array_reader.csh**

```
#!/bin/csh -f
### Test reading an array written from bash.

set THIS="$0"
# set THISDIR="$(readlink -f $(dirname ${THIS}))" # fails!
set THIS_DIRNAME=`dirname ${THIS}`
set THIS_DIR=`readlink -f ${THIS_DIRNAME}`
set THIS_FN=`basename ${THIS}`
set MESSAGE_PREFIX="${THIS_FN}:"
set ERROR_PREFIX="${MESSAGE_PREFIX} ERROR:"

if ( $?bdom ) then
  # Gotta convert passed string into a "real" csh array
  set bdom_array = ( $bdom )
  echo ${MESSAGE_PREFIX} found export=bdom, size=$#bdom_array":"
  printf "\t"          # continue on same line
  foreach item ( $bdom_array )
    printf "%d," $item # ditto
  end
  echo "" # newline to end the array-printing line
else
  echo "${ERROR_PREFIX} no export=bdom"
  exit 2
endif

echo "" # separate reports

if ( $?mday ) then
  set mday_array = ( $mday )
  echo ${MESSAGE_PREFIX} found export=mday, size=$#mday_array":"
  printf "\t"
  foreach item ( $mday_array )
    printf "%d," $item
  end
  echo "" # newline to end the array-printing line
else
  echo "${ERROR_PREFIX} no export=mday"
  exit 3
endif

exit 0
```

... then, from your shell, do ...

```
$ /path/to/array_writer.sh
array_writer.sh: YEAR='2007':
        BDOM=0,31,59,90,120,151,181,212,243,273,304,334
        MDAY=31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31
array_writer.sh: about to call /path/to/array_reader.csh:

array_reader.csh: found export=bdom, size=12:
        0,31,59,90,120,151,181,212,243,273,304,334,

array_reader.csh: found export=mday, size=12:
        31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31,

array_writer.sh: /path/to/array_reader.csh returned successfully
```

Comment: Interesting question and clearly you have spent time on this, but do we really need all of this? Can't we prove the issue in 2-4 lines each  of bash and csh? Can't you whittle this down to simpler test case? Good luck!

Comment: @shellter this is already whittled down from a much larger script that I'm debugging, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with arrays in csh, but exporting seems easy enough:

in bash:

```
bdom=${BDOM[*]} mday=${MDAY[*]} ${PARTNER_FP}
```

You don't need the "env" command, bash has that built in.

To make $bdom into a list of words, instead of a single string, use ().
in csh:

```
set bdom_array = ( $bdom )
```

Comment: This works! except for one annoyance with array size which I don't understand--no doubt due to my ignorance regarding csh. That being said, it's an annoyance I can ignore, and your answer is now part of the question.

Comment: @TomRoche The reasons is that `$bdom` is not an _array_, but a _string_ (that happens to contain a list of words and behaves similar to an array in certain situations, such as with `foreach`). As @rici points out: at present you can only export strings, not arrays (whether explicitly via `env` or `export`, or via an implicit `env` as in this solution). `$#someVar` in `csh` simply prints the variable value if the variable is a scalar; only genuine array variables return the count of elements.

Comment: This solution works well in the case at hand, but its constraints should be noted: The input array elements (a) must contain no embedded spaces or other characters that need escaping and (b) must contain no elements that happen to be valid globbing patterns (e.g., '*').

Comment: @mklement0 Thanks for pointing this out--I definitely don't know enough about working with/around (the evil that is :-) csh. I changed the title/question to hint at the constraint. Is there an example you can point to that solves the "general case" of bash-to-csh array passing?

Comment: @TomRoche I'm not sure there is a robust workaround that covers all cases. I know little about csh myself, but its string and array handling appears to be quite limited, as the following statement indicates: "In general, the C shell is not suited for variables that contain spaces" (http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Csh.html#uh-0)

Answer (score 1):

`bash` doesn't let you export arrays. ("Yet", although it's been "not yet" for a long time.) So it's not that there is a problem exporting arrays from `bash` to `csh`. You can't export them from `bash` to `bash` either. (Nor, as far as I know, from `csh` to `csh`.)

There isn't really a great workaround either. You could use the `printf` '`%q`' format to print the elements out in a format which could be `eval`'d, but you'd have to do that every time you changed an array element, or at least every time you might need to import it into a subshell. Also, `bash`'s `printf` doesn't necessarily export values in a format which `csh`'s `eval` will understand.

Answer (score 0):

As @rici points out, bash doesn't support exporting arrays - neither with `export` nor with `env` - and there's no robust workaround.

That said, **if** you know that:

- the array elements contain no embedded spaces or other characters that need escaping
- the array contains no elements that happen to be valid globbing patterns (e.g., '*')

then you can flatten your arrays into single-line, space-separated lists, and pass them that way.

In your example:

In `array_writer.sh`:

```
# export array as word list, i.e.:
# as single-line string with space-separated tokens
export BDOM_LIST="${BDOM[@]}"
```

In `array_reader.csh`:

```
# Convert word list back into array.
set BDOM=($BDOM_LIST)
```